# Why does this CSS "menu" sometimes render vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

So, a site i'm working on has a horizontal navigation menu. Here is the relevant code.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
        <li>About Us</li>
    </a>
    <a class="active" href="perspective.html">
        <li>Our Perspective</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul a li{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul a{
    color: #1d1d1d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold .8em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.nav ul a:hover li{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
}

.nav ul a.active li{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
}
```

You can view the site here: [pc.kraigh.com](http://pc.kraigh.com)

So, for some reason, every once in awhile, the list will render vertically, instead of horizontally. Also, sometimes (but not always) there will be bullets on each li, as if the browser is ignoring the list-style:none.

Is there something wrong with my CSS selectors that is causing this? Why would it only happen every once in awhile?

Note: To get the error to reproduce, try changing pages quickly, or refreshing the page a few times. Here is a (link to a) screenshot to prove that it sometimes happens!

[Screenshot of Error (Imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JubQH.png)

**EDIT:** Okay, I understand now that it needs to go `<ul><li><a>`, BUT, I wanted the entire `<li>` area to be clickable- not just the link text. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `ul`'s direct children must be `li`s! `<ul> <li><a>Title</a></li> <li>...`

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How do I make the entire li clickable then, not just the link text?

Comment: See my answer with the fixed css in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<li>` need to be direct children of `<ul>`:

This is correct:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="perspective.html">Our Perspective</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can assign a `width` and `line-height` to the `<li>` to make it completely clickable. Also, `padding` helps.

Comment: That's what I was doing at first, but I want the entire <li> area to be clickable, not just the link text. Is this possible?

Comment: set the CSS of the `<a>` to `display: inline-block` or `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that it has something to do with the fact that you are wrapping the `<li>` elements with the `<a>` tags.

Should be `<ul><li><a>`

The `<li>` tag should just be the holder, and the `<a>` tag the clickable part. Play around with the styles, maybe something like `display: block; padding: 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCnbB/2/

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="perspective.html">Our Perspective</a></li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

I modified the css a bit:

```
.nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Both `li` and `a` is `inline-block`, so `li` will be shrinkwrapped tightly to `a`.